# Concatenação de múltiplas listas com Python

Tags: python, array, web-scraping, scrapy

Boa tarde!

Estou com um problema e preciso de ajuda, estou trabalhando com 3 listas distintas que deverão ser adicionados a um dicionário, porem para que eu possa capturar todos os valores sem que um sobrescreva o outro, preciso concatenar essas 3 listas. Eu sei que usando ex: `list1.extend(list2)`, eu consigo concatenar, porem não sei se o mesmo se aplica para concatenação de múltiplas listas, existe algum outro meio de realizar essa concatenação? Segue estrutura do código, já mostrando o dicionário.

```
arrayDisciplinas = []
if response.xpath('//*[contains(a,"PDL")]//following-sibling::div//text()[not(re:test(.,"^\s+$"))]').extract() is not None:
    for linha in response.xpath('//*[contains(a,"PDL")]//following-sibling::div//text()[not(re:test(.,"^\s+$"))]').extract():
        disc = Disciplina()
        disc.set_all()
        if linha is not None:
            disc['Nome'] = linha.encode('utf-8')
        arrayDisciplinas.append(dict(disc))
        if len(arrayDisciplinas) > 0:
            disciplina = arrayDisciplinas

arrayDisciplinas2 = []
if response.xpath('//*[contains(a,"CLEO ESP")]//following-sibling::div//text()[not(re:test(.,"^\s+$"))]').extract() is not None:
    for linha in response.xpath('//*[contains(a,"CLEO ESP")]//following-sibling::div//text()[not(re:test(.,"^\s+$"))]').extract():
        disc2 = Disciplina()
        disc2.set_all()
        if linha is not None:
            disc2['Nome'] = linha.encode('utf-8')
        arrayDisciplinas2.append(dict(disc2))
        if len(arrayDisciplinas) > 0:
            disciplina2 = arrayDisciplinas2

arrayDisciplinas3 = []
if response.xpath('//*[contains(a,"CLEO ESTRUTURANTE")]//following-sibling::div//text()[not(re:test(.,"^\s+$"))]').extract() is not None:
    for linha in response.xpath('//*[contains(a,"CLEO ESTRUTURANTE")]//following-sibling::div//text()[not(re:test(.,"^\s+$"))]').extract():
        disc3 = Disciplina()
        disc3.set_all()
        if linha is not None:
            disc3['Nome'] = linha.encode('utf-8')
        arrayDisciplinas3.append(dict(disc3))
        if len(arrayDisciplinas) > 0:
            disciplina3 = arrayDisciplinas3

disciplina.extend(disciplina2)

item['Disciplinas'] = disciplina3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a pergunta em en-us: [How to merge multiple lists into one list in python? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574195/how-to-merge-multiple-lists-into-one-list-in-python) citaram 3 formas

### Forma 1: Importando o `itertools`

```
import itertools

iterable_disciplinas = itertools.chain(disciplina, disciplina2, disciplina3)
list(iterable_disciplinas)
```

### Forma 2: Usando o `extend`

Como vc já citou.

```
arrayDisciplinas = []

arrayDisciplinas.extend(disciplina)
arrayDisciplinas.extend(disciplina2)
arrayDisciplinas.extend(disciplina3)
```

### Forma 3: Usando operado `+`

```
disciplina + disciplina2 + disciplina3
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda de vocês, realmente a melhor situação pro meu caso foi utilizar a forma 2, seguindo o tutorial do GustavoRPS :).

Answer (score 2):

Se o problema é só concatenar as listas, a resposta do @GustavoRPS resolve. Se o problema é que existem listas dentro de listas, como:

```
disciplina1 = [1, [2,3]]
disciplina2 = [[4,5], 6, [[7,[8,9]]]]
```

Então você pode quebrar esses monstrinhos em uma lista unica assim:

```
def monstrinho_em_lista(lista):
    lista_final = []
    for item in lista:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            lista_final.extend(monstrinho_em_lista(item))
        else:
            lista_final.append(item)
    return lista_final
```

Assim:

```
>>> monstrinho_em_lista(disciplina2)
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

E ai é so concatenar.
Exemplo:

```
arrayDisciplinas = []

arrayDisciplinas.extend(monstrinho_em_lista(disciplina1))
arrayDisciplinas.extend(monstrinho_em_lista(disciplina2))
```