# Como concatenar itens de uma lista em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Digamos que eu tenha o resultado de uma lista:

```
['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
```

como posso transformar ela nisso?:

```
['_ _ _ _ _ _ _']
```

Ou até mesmo em uma variável com o valor acima

Comment: pode usar  for x in lista: ; resultado += x .  Se quiser escrevo uma resposta completa.

Comment: Ajudaria bastante,eu já estou tentando com o for mas não obtive sucesso..

Comment: Os itens da lista serão strings ?

Comment: Sim, preciso concatenar os item e adicionando um espeço entre cada um igual no exemplo

Comment: Então Danilo, a resposta abaixo, do Max resolve o seu problema. Mas se tiver que ter  uma formatação entre os itens da lista a resposta seria outra.

Comment: É bem parecido com [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322416/como-transformar-uma-lista-a-b-em-uma-string-ab/322434#322434), mas em vez de `''.join()` use `' '.join`. Se tiver listas dentro de listas sem padrão, você pode transformar em uma lista única ([assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/320976/concatena%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-m%C3%BAltiplas-listas-com-python/321004#321004)) e depois dar um `.join()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pode usar o `join` e depois transformar o retorno dele num array de um único elemento.

```
separator = ' '
array = ['_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_', '_']
result = [separator.join(array)]
print(result)
```

O print será:

```
['_ _ _ _ _ _ _']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Pode usar assim também para ficar com menos linhas.**

```
array = ['_', '_', '_', '_']
result = [' '.join(array)]
print(result)
```

**Resultado:**

```
['_ _ _ _']
```

Comment: Se for só para ficar com menos linhas, poderia ser `print([' '.join(['_', '_', '_', '_'])])` :D Aliás, não entendi bem o porquê da resposta, sendo que a única coisa que mudou foi não usar uma variável como separador.

Comment: Sou novo na área haha, o seu jeito é melhor mesmo

Comment: Não veja pelo lado ruim. Só comentei realmente porque não entendi o motivo da resposta, visto que é a mesma solução, sem benefícios ou malefícios. Costumamos sempre responder quando há alguma diferença que valha a citação. De qualquer forma, seja bem-vindo à comunidade. Recomendo que faça o [tour] para se interar sobre o básico do site.

Answer (score -1):

Consegue com uma linha:

```
return " ".join(lista.split()[::-1])
```